# Cannot not install flash Player because libnss3-1d is missing

Tags: linux, flash, firefox, dependencies, ubuntu-14.04

Cannot not install flash Player because libnss3-1d is missing.  I am also not able to install libness3-1d as well.

For the Flash Player I get this error:
***The following packages have unmet dependencies:
flashplugin-installer : Depends: libnss3-1d but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.***

For the libnss3-1d I get this error:
***Package libnss3-1d is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'libnss3-1d' has no installation candidate***

I did have Google Chrome on but it kept locking up my computer so I removed it.  I had to do a hard restart. Aka the power switch.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

Open Ubuntu Software Centre and serach for "Adobe Flash Plugin" and install it from there.
It will take care of the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your libnss3 is not up to date or it's showing libniss3 already to the latest version, however, it is not, you can manually install 
by following steps

1. Download it from the link->
   https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libnss3/download
2. then move to the folder where you have downloaded the file in the terminal
3. install by running the following command in the terminal

   **sudo dpkg -i libnss3_3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_amd64.deb**

4.know your libnss3 is updated to latest version.